# Why tempdata attribute retain after first read?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, tempdata

It spose that tempdata read once and disposed and that was ok before using it as attribute now when using it like attribute it retain to next request after read for first time
here is my sample code
Page A

```
public class AModel : PageModel
    {
        [TempData]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "test Page A";
        }
    }

<h1>A</h1>
    
<p>@Model.Message</p>

<a asp-page="b">Page B</a>
```

Page B

```
    public class BModel : PageModel
{
    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}

<h1>B</h1>

<p>@Model.Message</p>

<a asp-page="A">Page A</a>
```

when navigating from page A to page b it should not showing the message from page A but i got the message appear in page B the result look like that

B
test Page A

Page A

Answer (score 2):

> when navigating from page A to page b it should not showing the message from page A

If you do a test with following code, you would easily find that the code snippet `@Model.Message` in `A.cshtml` does not read TempData value.

```
<h1>A</h1>

using TempData["Message"]: <p>@TempData["Message"]</p>
<hr />
using Model.Message: <p>@Model.Message</p>
<hr />
using TempData.Peek("Message"): <p>@TempData.Peek("Message")</p>
<hr />
using Model.Message: <p>@Model.Message</p>

<a asp-page="b">Page B</a>
```

*The output of above testing*

[image]

And as mentoned about TempData in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tempdata):

```
This property stores data until it's read in another request.
```

Comment: Please note that "stores data until it's read in **another request**".

Comment: is there is deferent between using tempdata[message] and give property message attribute tempdata the first work ok not shoing in page B the second showing in page a and b

Comment: If you compare the cookie (or set-cookie header), you would find the tempdata related cookie `.AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider` is no value [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omWYL.png) while using `@TempData["message"]` in A.cshtml to access the value, so the value not showing in page B.